# deploying Spring boot in websphere

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-8

**Websphere 8.5.5.2**

Trying to deploy spring boot application in to websphere server. I already made sure class loader policy is parent last. Issue seems because websphere may need some additional configuration to recognize war without any web.xml? Not sure. Getting below error.

**Caused by:** `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/usr/WebSphere850/AppServer/endorsed_apis/jaxb-api.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class`

to

`wsjar:file:/usr/WebSphere850/AppServer/profiles/node01/installedApps/dchislwsapp020Cell01/My%20Application%20Service%20-%20Test%20Service.ear/test-plan-rest.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class`.Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.`

Comment: WebSphere already provides JAXB, please try to remove `WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar` from your application.

Comment: But parent last should take care of that, right ?

Comment: Not necessarily, as JAXB is not Spring boot library, but library used by server for other features like for example JAXWS also. So it might require disabling some other features, if you are using third party implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by adding

`DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true`

to your application's `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to disable it at the application level.

To disable it at the server level follow the directions at: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_6.1.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html?cp=SS7JFU_6.1.0%2F1-7-9-4-1-14-0 to disable at the server level.